# How to Test an SQL Field Type in Java Before Inserting Data

Tags: java, mariadb

I am looking for some guidance on how (or if there is a way) to test a db field type when performing an INSERT statement in order to work around the "Incorrect integer value" exception.

The issue I am running into is my program is reading from a csv data source and may contain fields that are empty destined for an integer field. When I try to insert this empty string into an INT field it raises that exception.

In the snippet of code (I have about 50 fields total to update, but scaled down the code for simplicity), I've created a CheckField function to iterate over all fields, but it has obvious hard-coded limitations if an "N/A" shows up, etc. I prefer to use a loop for the setString because of the number of fields to update vs. having 50 setString statements.

I've looked at ResultSetMetaData and it has what I am looking for with "getColumnTypeName" but I believe that only applies to SELECT statements and not UPDATE (maybe?).

```
int field[] = {3, 4, 0};

String updateTable = "UPDATE test_table F1 = ?, F2 = ? WHERE F0 = ?"

PreparedStatement update = conMaria.prepareStatement(updateTable);

Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.RFC4180.withFirstRecordAsHeader().parse(in);
for (CSVRecord record : records) {
    for (int i = 0; i < field.length; i++)
        update.setString(i + 1, CheckField(record.get(field[i])));
    update.executeUpdate();

public static String CheckField(String recordValue) {
    return recordValue.equals("") ? null : recordValue;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Hibernate and a mapping Entity class for your table? With something like Spring Boot you can easily insert and update data using data repositories.
As the member types in your Entity class would match the table column types there would be no need to request the types from the DB itself. Furthermore using these Entity classes would allow you to specify default values.

Comment: Thanks. I am not familiar with Hibernate, but I'll take a look and see how I can apply it. I still find it perplexing that Java doesn't have a built-in java.sql method that can load table meta data and allow you to check the field type. :(

Answer (score 0):

1. create a table with 50 varchar columns,
2. `LOAD DATA` to populate it,
3. run several SQL commands to check the columns, fix the bad values, delete rows that can't be repaired, etc, etc.
4. Finally, copy the cleansed data into the 'real' table.

No Java code is involved.  You get a bunch of SQL practice.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO `real` (...)
    SELECT ..., IF(foo = '', 0, foo), ...
        FROM `staging`;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot discard a row, so I would have to find a way around testing for a string value and replacing it with null when it is applied to a INT field. But LOAD DATA is something I could explore. Thanks.

Comment: @Stephen - I provided a simple example.